# Autowired variables inside HATEOAS links

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas, application.properties

Can't resolve autowired value inside Hateoas link

`http://localhost:8080/${api.version}/api/messages/123`

application.properties

```
api.version=v1
```

Spring Parent Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value={"${api.version}/api"})
public class BaseRestController {}
```

Some controller required HATEOAS self link

```
@RestController
public class SomeController extends BaseRestController { 
// constructor

@RequestMapping(value = "/messages/{messageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Alert> getAlert(@PathVariable("messageId") String messageId) {

    Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(SomeController.class).getAlert(messageId, null)).withSelfRel();
    System.out.println(selfLink.getHref());

    // more code
}
```

I can do string replacement, but if there is a better way or someone might had same issue, please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: That should work the way you do it. Can you test with `@Value("${api.version}") private String apiVersion;` and logging the value in a suitable place if property injection properly works in your Spring framework setup?

Comment: I can autowire and log @Value("${api.version}"), but seems there is no way to make nice hateoas url based on RequestMapping with values from application.properties. Try it if you have any Spring Boot application running. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue actually when I was implementing and creating some Spring Boot projects. It seems that Spring HATEOAS WebMvcLinkBuilder will get the text string assigned on the URI mapping of the controller class before it will be injected by the value from the application.properties. As what I understand, I suspect that HATEOAS WebMvcLinkBuilder doesn't rely on the injected value of the mapped URI of controller bean but rather on the raw text string itself.

I just used Spring manipulation and Link withHref and getHref methods.

```
@Value(API_VERSION)
private String apiVersion;


//inside a method
Link link  = linkTo(methodOn(SomeController.class).getAlert(messageId, null)).withSelfRel();
link.withHref(link.getHref().replace("${api.version}", urlBrand));
```

Comment: I like that someone voted my question and answer as -1 :) Whatever makes you happy USER! Thanks for adding additional implementation

Comment: `withHref` returns another link. So it's better to use `link = link.withHref...` in the last line

Answer (score 0):

As I can't find an answer so far, did simple URL parser:

application.properties

```
api.version=v1
```

Resource assembler

```
@Component
public class AlertResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<Alert, Resource<Alert>> {

public static final String API_VERSION = "${api.version}";

@Value(API_VERSION)
private String apiVersion;

@Override
public Resource toResource(Alert alert) {

    String messageId = alert.getMessageId();

    Resource<Alert> resource = new Resource<>(alert);

    resource.add(createLink(Link.REL_SELF, linkTo(methodOn(SomeController .class).getAlert(messageId, null))).withSelfRel());
    resource.add(createLink("comments", linkTo(methodOn(SomeController .class).getUserComments(messageId, null))));

    return resource;
}

private Link createLink(String rel, ControllerLinkBuilder linkBuilder) {
    final Map<String, String> urlParameters = createParams();

    String href = linkBuilder.withSelfRel().getHref();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : urlParameters.entrySet()) {
        href = href.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return new Link(href, rel);
}

private Map<String, String> createParams() {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put(API_VERSION, "/" + apiVersion);
    return parameters;
}
}
```